# unhandled exception - Update unable to find TableMapping

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I can't seem to figure out this error I'm getting when trying to save a new record set, my Form loads, when I fill in all the fields and click the save button to get a record inserted into my Access Database I receive the following error

(Error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Update unable to find TableMapping['Clients'] or DataTable 'Clients'.)

Code

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Friend Class Client

    Dim daClient As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim dsClient As New DataSet()

    Public ID As String

    Public State As AccessModule.FormState

    Private Sub ClientBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Me.Validate()
        Me.ClientBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.LoginDataSet)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Client_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'LoginDataSet.Client' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.ClientTableAdapter.Fill(Me.LoginDataSet.Client)


        Dim cnClient As OleDbConnection

        cnClient = New OleDbConnection

        Try
            With cnClient
                If .State = ConnectionState.Open Then .Close()

                .ConnectionString = cnString
                .Open()
            End With
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

        If State = AccessModule.FormState.adStateAddMode Then
            Try
                Dim qryClient As String = "SELECT * FROM Client"

                daClient.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(qryClient, cnClient)

                Dim cb As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(daClient)

                daClient.Fill(dsClient, "Client")
            Catch ex As OleDbException
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            Finally
                cnClient.Close()
            End Try
        ElseIf State = AccessModule.FormState.adStateEditMode Then
            Dim qryClient As String = "SELECT * FROM Client WHERE ID = '" & ID & "'"

            daClient.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(qryClient, cnClient)

            Dim cb As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(daClient)

            daClient.Fill(dsClient, "Client")

            Dim dt As DataTable = dsClient.Tables("Client")

            Try
                IDTextBox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("ID")
                FnameTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Fname")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Fname"))
                LnameTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Lname")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Lname"))
                MnameTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Mname")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Mname"))
                SexeComboBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Sexe")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Sexe"))
                BdateDateTimePicker.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Bdate")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Bdate"))
                AgeTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Age")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Age"))
                DdateDateTimePicker.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Ddate")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Ddate"))
                DplaceTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Dplace")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Dplace"))
                SINTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("SIN")), "", dt.Rows(0)("SIN"))
                OccuTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Occu")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Occu"))
                OccuTTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("OccuT")), "", dt.Rows(0)("OccuT"))
                StreetTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Street")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Street"))
                CityTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("CIty")), "", dt.Rows(0)("City"))
                ProvTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Prov")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Prov"))
                CountryTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Country")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Country"))
                PcodeTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Pcode")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Pcode"))
                TelTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Tel")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Tel"))
                FaxTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Fax")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Fax"))
                EmailTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Email")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Email"))
                ID1TextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("ID1")), "", dt.Rows(0)("ID1"))
                ID2TextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("ID2")), "", dt.Rows(0)("ID2"))
                ID3TextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("ID3")), "", dt.Rows(0)("ID3"))
                LicenseTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("License")), "", dt.Rows(0)("License"))
                RelationComboBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Relation")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Relation"))
                RoleComboBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Role")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Role"))
                Vday1DateTimePicker.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Vday1")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Vday1"))
                Vday1LocTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Vday1Loc")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Vday1Loc"))
                Vday1YTimeTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Vday1YTime")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Vday1YTime"))
                Vday2DateTimePicker.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Vday2")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Vday2"))
                Vday2LocTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Vday2Loc")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Vday2Loc"))
                Vday2TimeTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Vday2Time")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Vday2Time"))
                Prayer1DateTimePicker.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Prayer1")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Prayer1"))
                Prayer1TimeTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Prayer1Time")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Prayer1Time"))
                Prayer1LocTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Prayer1Loc")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Prayer1Loc"))

                Service1DateTimePicker.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Service1")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Service1"))
                Service1LocTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Service1Loc")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Service1Loc"))
                Service1TimeTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("Service1Time")), "", dt.Rows(0)("Service1Time"))
                DispoTypeComboBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("DispoType")), "", dt.Rows(0)("DispoType"))
                DispoDateDateTimePicker.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("DispoDate")), "", dt.Rows(0)("DispoDate"))
                DispoTimeTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("DispoTime")), "", dt.Rows(0)("DispoTime"))
                DispoLocTextBox.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("DispoLoc")), "", dt.Rows(0)("DispoLoc"))

            Catch ex As OleDbException
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            Finally
                cnClient.Close()
            End Try
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        Dim dt As DataTable = dsClient.Tables("Client")

        If IDTextBox.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please fill At Need Number", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

            Exit Sub
        End If

        Try
            If State = AccessModule.FormState.adStateAddMode Then
                ' add a row
                Dim newRow As DataRow

                newRow = dt.NewRow()

                newRow("ID") = IDTextBox.Text
                newRow("Fname") = IIf(FnameTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, FnameTextBox.Text)
                newRow("Lname") = IIf(LnameTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, LnameTextBox.Text)
                newRow("Mname") = IIf(MnameTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, MnameTextBox.Text)
                newRow("Sexe") = IIf(SexeComboBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, SexeComboBox.Text)
                newRow("Bdate") = IIf(BdateDateTimePicker.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, BdateDateTimePicker.Text)
                newRow("Bplace") = IIf(BplaceTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, BplaceTextBox.Text)
                newRow("Age") = IIf(AgeTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, AgeTextBox.Text)
                newRow("Ddate") = IIf(DdateDateTimePicker.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, DdateDateTimePicker.Text)
                newRow("Dplace") = IIf(DplaceTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, DplaceTextBox.Text)
                newRow("SIN") = IIf(SINTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, SINTextBox.Text)
                newRow("Occu") = IIf(OccuTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, OccuTextBox.Text)
                newRow("OccuT") = IIf(OccuTTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, OccuTTextBox.Text)
                newRow("Street") = IIf(StreetTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, StreetTextBox.Text)
                newRow("City") = IIf(CityTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, CityTextBox.Text)
                newRow("Country") = IIf(CountryTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, CountryTextBox.Text)
                newRow("Pcode") = IIf(PcodeTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, PcodeTextBox.Text)
                newRow("Tel") = IIf(TelTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, TelTextBox.Text)
                newRow("Fax") = IIf(FaxTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, FaxTextBox.Text)
                newRow("Email") = IIf(EmailTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, EmailTextBox.Text)
                newRow("ID1") = IIf(ID1TextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, ID1TextBox.Text)
                newRow("ID2") = IIf(ID2TextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, ID2TextBox.Text)
                newRow("ID3") = IIf(ID3TextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, ID3TextBox.Text)
                newRow("License") = IIf(LicenseTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, LicenseTextBox.Text)
                newRow("Relation") = IIf(RelationComboBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, RelationComboBox.Text)
                newRow("Role") = IIf(RoleComboBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, RoleComboBox.Text)
                newRow("Vday1") = IIf(Vday1DateTimePicker.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Vday1DateTimePicker.Text)
                newRow("Vday1Loc") = IIf(Vday1LocTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Vday1LocTextBox.Text)
                newRow("Vday1YTime") = IIf(Vday1YTimeTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Vday1YTimeTextBox.Text)
                newRow("Vday2") = IIf(Vday2DateTimePicker.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Vday2DateTimePicker.Text)
                newRow("Vday2Loc") = IIf(Vday2LocTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Vday2LocTextBox.Text)
                newRow("Vday2Time") = IIf(Vday2TimeTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Vday2TimeTextBox.Text)
                newRow("Prayer1") = IIf(Prayer1DateTimePicker.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Prayer1DateTimePicker.Text)
                newRow("Prayer1Time") = IIf(Prayer1TimeTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Prayer1TimeTextBox.Text)
                newRow("Prayer1Loc") = IIf(Prayer1LocTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Prayer1LocTextBox.Text)
                newRow("Service1") = IIf(Service1DateTimePicker.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Service1DateTimePicker.Text)
                newRow("Service1Loc") = IIf(Service1LocTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Service1LocTextBox.Text)
                newRow("Service1Time") = IIf(Service1TimeTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Service1TimeTextBox.Text)
                newRow("DispoType") = IIf(DispoTypeComboBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, DispoTypeComboBox.Text)
                newRow("DispoDate") = IIf(DispoDateDateTimePicker.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, DispoDateDateTimePicker.Text)
                newRow("DispoTime") = IIf(DispoTimeTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, DispoTimeTextBox.Text)
                newRow("DispoLoc") = IIf(DispoLocTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, DispoLocTextBox.Text)

                dt.Rows.Add(newRow)
            Else
                With dt
                    .Rows(0)("ID") = IDTextBox.Text
                    .Rows(0)("Fname") = IIf(FnameTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, FnameTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Lname") = IIf(LnameTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, LnameTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Mname") = IIf(MnameTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, MnameTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Sexe") = IIf(SexeComboBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, SexeComboBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Bdate") = IIf(BdateDateTimePicker.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, BdateDateTimePicker.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Bplace") = IIf(BplaceTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, BplaceTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Age") = IIf(AgeTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, AgeTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Ddate") = IIf(DdateDateTimePicker.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, DdateDateTimePicker.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Dplace") = IIf(DplaceTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, DplaceTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("SIN") = IIf(SINTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, SINTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Occu") = IIf(OccuTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, OccuTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("OccuT") = IIf(OccuTTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, OccuTTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Street") = IIf(StreetTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, StreetTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("City") = IIf(CityTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, CityTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Country") = IIf(CountryTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, CountryTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Pcode") = IIf(PcodeTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, PcodeTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Tel") = IIf(TelTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, TelTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Fax") = IIf(FaxTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, FaxTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Email") = IIf(EmailTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, EmailTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("ID1") = IIf(ID1TextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, ID1TextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("ID2") = IIf(ID2TextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, ID2TextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("ID3") = IIf(ID3TextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, ID3TextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("License") = IIf(LicenseTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, LicenseTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Relation") = IIf(RelationComboBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, RelationComboBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Role") = IIf(RoleComboBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, RoleComboBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Vday1") = IIf(Vday1DateTimePicker.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Vday1DateTimePicker.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Vday1Loc") = IIf(Vday1LocTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Vday1LocTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Vday1YTime") = IIf(Vday1YTimeTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Vday1YTimeTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Vday2") = IIf(Vday2DateTimePicker.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Vday2DateTimePicker.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Vday2Loc") = IIf(Vday2LocTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Vday2LocTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Vday2Time") = IIf(Vday2TimeTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Vday2TimeTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Prayer1") = IIf(Prayer1DateTimePicker.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Prayer1DateTimePicker.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Prayer1Time") = IIf(Prayer1TimeTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Prayer1TimeTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Prayer1Loc") = IIf(Prayer1LocTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Prayer1LocTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Service1") = IIf(Service1DateTimePicker.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Service1DateTimePicker.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Service1Loc") = IIf(Service1LocTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Service1LocTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("Service1Time") = IIf(Service1TimeTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, Service1TimeTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("DispoType") = IIf(DispoTypeComboBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, DispoTypeComboBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("DispoDate") = IIf(DispoDateDateTimePicker.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, DispoDateDateTimePicker.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("DispoTime") = IIf(DispoTimeTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, DispoTimeTextBox.Text)
                    .Rows(0)("DispoLoc") = IIf(DispoLocTextBox.Text = "", System.DBNull.Value, DispoLocTextBox.Text)


                End With
            End If
            daClient.Update(dsClient, "Clients")

            MsgBox("Record successfully saved.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The table name is `"Client"` everywhere except for on this line:

```
daClient.Update(dsClient, "Clients")
```

I bet you need to change that to

```
daClient.Update(dsClient, "Client")
```